# What should our [approach] be?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

The tag [approach](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approach) currently has currently five questions. Based on those five, the meaning of the tag is "what should my approach be to ...?"
In other words, "how do I ...?", which is basically *every* question here.

Therefore, [approach](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/approach) has no use and should be deleted.